# Display same values in rows in mysql and print column value and it's count in php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to make a voting list kind of thing. I have a form that saves the entered data to mysql database. Suppose a user entered "Something". It'll be saved in column called "bname". Now what I want is Suppose 10 people entered "Something" or "something"(case sensitivity to be ignored automatically if there is a way?) then I want: "Something - 10" to be printed in php page.

My try:

```
$query="SELECT bname, count 
FROM brandnames 
GROUP BY bname 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 0
LIMIT 11";

$result=mysqli_query($con,$query) or die('Error!: ' . mysqli_error($con));

$query2="SELECT count
FROM brandnames
GROUP BY count
HAVING COUNT(*) > 0
ORDER BY count DESC
LIMIT 11";

$result2=mysqli_query($con,$query2) or die('Counting Error!: ' . mysqli_error($con));

while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
while ($row2=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2))
{
echo ($row['bname'] . '&nbsp' . '-' . '&nbsp' . $row2['count'] . '<br />');
}
}
```

This thing prints
Something - 4
Something - 3

I do not want to use this method. I posted this as if I don't post someone will point me out to post. :/

I don't want to use "count" column. I want a simple voting list as I mentioned above.

Thanks, :)

Comment: You need to use `SELECT count(*) AS ...` and `GROUP BY`

Comment: I wrote I posted this syntax just to show that I tried. I don't want to use this method. :) Anyways thanks

Comment: read the comment above again. there is no count column, there is count(*) function, which counts rows in the table. no extra column.

Comment: you want to count how many times 'something' was written, why don't you want to use the function made for that?

Comment: @Sebas I want duplicate 'something' to be printed as 1 something that is 1 query and I want to print the no. of times 'something' was entered in front of 'something'.

Answer (score 1):

The query your looking for should be something like

```
select bname, count(*) as nbr
  from brandnames
 group by bname
 order by nbr desc
limit 11;
```

count(*) will return the number of rows that was grouped together by bname. Case sensitivity is depending on your coalition. If it's a case sensitive coaltion you need to group by lower(bname) instead. Be aware thou that this might prevent indexes from working for this query.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all of you. I got to know how to do this. Hope this helps someone :)
Special thanks to @Andreas Wederbrand

```
<?php

//Create Connection

$query="SELECT columnname, count(*)
AS alias
FROM tablename
GROUP BY columnname
ORDER BY alias DESC";

$result=mysqli_query($con,$query) or die('Counting Error!: ' . mysqli_error($con));



while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo ($row['columnname'] . '&nbsp' . '-' . '&nbsp' . $row['alias'] . '<br />');
}

//Close Connection
?>
```